# Pie chart icon placing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, pie-chart, label

I have a problem when trying to draw a pie chart.
[image: Design example]

Of course, there is no problem with drawing the chart, the problem is the icon placement.
Ideally, the icons should be placed on a circle (let's forget the percent labels for now).

However, the design obviously breaks when there are neighbor items with small values.

[image: Implementation example]

Could you recommend an algorithm solving this issue? To simplify, as input we have:
`PIE_RADIUS` - The outer radius of the pie.
`ICON_RADIUS` - The radius of the icon circle.
`ICON_PLACEMENT_RADIUS` - The radius of the circle when icon center should be ideally placed.
`NUM_ICONS` - Number of icons to place.
`iconAngles` Angle for every icon, in the center of its section

Required output:
Either `iconAngles` for items placed around the pie or `iconPositions` when moving the icons out of their ideal circle.

I know how to check whether two icons overlap.
We can consider the center of the pie to be at `(0, 0)`.

(The implementation is part of an iOS application but I am interested in a general algorihm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I implemented was the following:

1. Calculate the position for all the icons relative to their slice (icon centered on `ICON_PLACEMENT_RADIUS`)
2. Find sequences of overlapping icons (iterate the icons and check if the next is overlapping with the previous).
3. Calculate the minimum angular distance between two icons (approximately `(2.0f * ICON_RADIUS + 1.0f) / ICON_PLACEMENT_RADIUS`)
4. Calculate the center of the sequence (sum all the slices for the sequence and find the center), place the icons together (distance between them is the minimum angular distance).
5. When all icons placed, check if icons overlap, if yes, merge their sequences and iterate.

Note this algorithm works only if all the number of icons is small comparing to the size of the circle but it's simple and very fast.

The result is:
[image]

Comment: This is not the best possible solution but it's good enough and very simple to implement. For anyone reading this, please, read the other answers, too.

Comment: Sulthan - Hi, do you care sharing the complete solution? I will hugely appreciate the code itself, I do need it for Android, but iOS example will also be great as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

A first naive algorithm , we "push" the icons that overlap with an other icon:

```
FOR iconToPlace in icons do:
    isPlaced = false

    WHILE(not isPlaced) DO:
        isPlaced = true
        FOR icon in icons DO:
            IF overlap(iconToPlace, icon) AND iconToPlace != icon THEN:
                isPlaced = false
                push(iconToPlace) // same angle but the icon is now further
                BREAK
            ENDIF
        ENDFOR
    ENDWHILE

ENDFOR
```

With this first algorithm some icons will be futher from the center than other. But it does not exploit the possible place by changing the angle. By applying this to your second design (with small values) it is clear that the solution will be far away from the ideal one.

A second less naive algorithm, first we allocate a new angle (difference less than DeltaAngleMax) for each icon then we apply the first algo:

```
icons = SORT(icons)
iconsRef = icons
isFinished = false
WHILE(not isFinished) DO:
    isFinished = true
    FOR i = 0 TO i = NUM_ICONS-1 DO:
        IF   overlap(icons(i), icons(i+1 % NUM_ICONS))
         AND not overlap(icons(i), icons(i-1 % NUM_ICONS)) //seems useless
         AND not overlap(icons(i)-DeltaAngle % 360, icons(i-1 % NUM_ICONS))
         AND ABS(icons(i)-iconsRef(i)) <= DeltaAngleMax THEN:
            //overlap with next icon but not with previous, 
            //if we decrease angle we still not overlap with previous icon and
            //the futur delta angle is less than DeltaAngleMax
            //then we can move the icon :
            icons(i) = icons(i)-DeltaAngle
            isFinished = false
        ELSE IF   overlap(icons(i), icons(i-1 % NUM_ICONS))
         AND not overlap(icons(i), icons(i+1 % NUM_ICONS))  //seems useless
         AND not overlap(icons(i)+DeltaAngle % 360, icons(i+1 % NUM_ICONS))
         AND ABS(icons(i)-iconsRef(i)) <= DeltaAngleMax THEN:
            //vice et versa:
            icons(i) = icons(i)+DeltaAngle
            isFinished = false
    ENDFOR
ENDWHILE

APPLY_FIRST_ALGO
```

Choose wisely deltaAngle and DeltaAngleMax. A too little deltaAngle will lead to a big running time.

To go further you should have a look at [the force-directed graph drawing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-based_algorithms_%28graph_drawing%29) algorithm which is much more robust method to achieve your goal, one of the difficulty is to find the correct forces of the nodes (your icons, you have no edges).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I did implement it changing only the angles because the `push` method you mention is very tricky to implement, too. Thanks for the link, I will definitely study the algorithm. However, I was looking for simple solutions, something a programmer can implement in a day (or two). A chart drawing library could implement some advanced algorithm but normal programmers don't have the time and have to find algorithms that are not perfect, only good enough.

Comment: An other solution is to change the angle then if it occurs that some overlaps are still present you increase the ICON_PLACEMENT_RADIUS. About the `push` method i don't know your coordinate system but it is easy to switch between Polar and Cartesian and with polar `push` is just increase the distance from origin (perfect in your case since the center of the pie is at (0,0)).

Comment: If you just do it this way, you will increase the total space required to draw the pie. I tried that solution but it doesn't look good. Especially when there are multiple icons almost at the same place.

Answer (score 1):

Just brainstorming:

A genetic algorithm with a fitness function that has a high penalty for overlaps plus a penalty equal to the sum of the squares of the angular distances between each candidate location and its ideal location (centered relative to its slice).

Comment: I saw a solution on the internet using genetic algorithms but it seemed too complicated for my use case. However, if I was implementing a chart drawing library, I would definitely go for genetic algorithms.